# How to set default value ion-select item?

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I need to set default value to ion-select item.

[image]

The ion-select above contain list of places, After choosing a place I save it into a localStorage.

What I need this localStorage be the default value of the ion-select,like this:

[image]

> When the page is changed the ion-select return the placeHolder and no item is selected

*CODE*:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-select multiple="false" placeholder="Which Place?" [(ngModel)]="placeId" (ionChange)="showPlace()"> 
      <ion-option class="text-input place-field" *ngFor="let place of places | async;let i = index" value="{{place.id}}"> 
        {{place.name}}
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: Possible dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146350/how-to-set-default-selected-value-of-ion-option
did you try: `this.placeId = local.storage.getItem('yourValue')` in your component?

Comment: Thanks @mxr7350 for your replaying, I tried but didn't work.

Comment: will the places array value change or its the same all the time

Comment: @MaheshJadhav changes, it is an observable list

Comment: so will the house index change next time we load the page or will the house always stay at example say index '0' or whatever it may everytime

Comment: Yes house stay the same index if an element is added to the list it will be added on the bottom @MaheshJadhav

Comment: ok great the do one thing while saving to local-storage save its index value instead or if you want the full name save it with name and index and then while fetching from local-storage take its index value and then selected property will work

Comment: If i have the index how can i select the item from their index? Can u create an answer instead the comment please thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to that..
add a AbstractControl to your [(ngModel)].

example:
in yout TS file..

```
placeForm: FormGroup;
placeId: AbstractControl;

constructor(){
  this.placeForm.formBuilder.group({
   placeId: ['', Validators.required],
  });
  this.placeForm.get('placeId').setValue(place.id);
}
```

in your html
just add this `[(ngModel)]="placeForm.placeId"`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the index value you can just fetch that from localstorage and when the page loads you can save it in a variable and then use it to bind to the selected property on ion-option:

html:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-select multiple="false" placeholder="Which Place?" [(ngModel)]="placeId" (ionChange)="showPlace()"> 
    <ion-option class="text-input place-field" *ngFor="let place of places | async;let i = index" [selected]="i == selectedIndex" value="{{place.id}}"> // the variable selected index will be a number and will select the item matching with the index from the array.
    {{place.name}}
    </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

in ts:

```
selectedIndex: number;

constructor(){
  this.selectedIndex = localStorage.getItem('index') // 
}
```

Comment: I tried you  method doesn't work,, I tried to hard code it `[selected]="i==1"`

Comment: No error just the ion-select not selecting any think

Comment: and can you please check what are you getting inside selectedIndex is that a number or string

Answer (score 0):

I solved

the ion-select have the two way data binding with `placeId`

```
<ion-select multiple="false" placeholder="Which Place?" [(ngModel)]="placeId" (ionChange)="showPlace()"> 
  <ion-option class="text-input place-field" *ngFor="let place of places | async;" value="{{place.id}}"> 
    {{place.name}}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

After Selecting a place I saved the id of the selected place inside the local storage. Then on the `ionViewDidLoad()` I init the the variable `this.placeId`

`this.placeId = localstorage.getItem('foo')`

and it work properly.

> My mistake: I was saving the name of the place in the localstorage and not the id of the place

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

In ionic 4

```
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    let parametros = this.navParams.get('parametros');
    this.cuentaBancaria.empresa._id = parametros.empresa;
    this.cuentaBancaria.moneda._id = parametros.moneda;
  }
```

Comment: I dont follow..  Can you explain?