# How to set default selected value of multiple options(ion-select)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-select

I am trying to have certain pre-selected values in my`ion-select` checkbox, but I was unable to find any answers. The values I want pre-selected have the value in my object as `checked=true`.

```js
private totalPPE:any = [
    {id: 0,text:"Gloves",checked:true},
    {id: 1,text:"Glasses/Goggles/Face-Shield",checked:true},
    {id: 2,text:"Hard Hat",checked:true},
    {id: 3,text:"Hearing Protection",checked:false},
    {id: 4,text:"FR Attire",checked:true},
    {id: 5,text:"Steel Toe Boots",checked:true},
    {id: 6,text:"Fall Protection",checked:false},
    {id: 7,text:"H2S Monitor",checked:false},
    {id: 8,text:"Respiratory Protection",checked:false},
    {id: 9,text:"Other",checked:false}];
```

```html
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>PPE REQUIRED FOR TASK</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="totalPPE" name="ppe" multiple="true">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let ppe of totalPPE; let i = index" [selected]="ppe.checked=='true'" [value]=ppe.text>{{ppe.text}}</ion-option>
       </ion-select>
     </ion-item>
```

All of the resources I tried following unfortunately didn't work for me. I even tried the question, [How to set default selected value of ion-option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146350/how-to-set-default-selected-value-of-ion-option)
 , but unfortunately I found no solutions either.

Comment: just `[selected]="ppe.checked"` should do?

Comment: @Aragorn Unfortunately I tried, doesn't work.

Comment: You may want to try to bind the ngModel to another simple array, I'm not sure if ion-select can update the complex array that you have. Use that totalPPE array only for ion-options.

Comment: You can try to use `compareWith` property to manage Object Value References in ion-select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was the object array. I don't believe Ionic can handle them so I changed the array to this:

```js
private totalPPE:any = ["Gloves",
                        "Glasses/Goggles/Face-Shield",
                        "Hard Hat",
                        "Hearing Protection",
                        "FR Attire",
                        "Steel Toe Boots",
                        "Fall Protection",
                        "H2S Monitor",
                        "Respiratory Protection",
                        "Other"];
```

And added another array for default values:

```js
private defaultPPE:any = ["Gloves",
                          "Glasses/Goggles/Face-Shield",
                          "Hard Hat",
                          "FR Attire",
                          "Steel Toe Boots"];
```

And changed my HTML:

```html
<ion-item>
   <ion-label class="ppe">PPE REQUIRED FOR TASK</ion-label>
       <ion-select [(ngModel)]="defaultPPE" name="ppe" multiple="true">
         <ion-option *ngFor="let ppe of totalPPE" value={{ppe}} >{{ppe}}</ion-option>
       </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```